# Is it possible to use multiple authentication types with nginx ingress?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have some internal services (Logging, Monitoring, etc) exposed via nginx-ingress and protected via oauth2-proxy and some identity manager (Okta) behind. We use 2fa for additional security for our users.

This works great for user accounts. It does not work for other systems like external monitoring as we can not make a request with a token or basic auth credentials.

Is there any known solution to enable multiple authentication types in an ingress resource?

Everything I found so far is specific for one authentication process and trying to add basic auth as well did not work.

Current ingress

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: cert-manager-extra-issuer
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: https://sso-proxy/oauth2/start?rd=https://$host$request_uri
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: https://sso-proxy/oauth2/auth
```

Answer (score 1):

This is simply not an advisable solution. You cannot use multiple authentication types in a single Ingress resource.

The better way to deal with it would be to create separate Ingresses for different authentication types.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Have you tried with separate Ingresses for different authentication types?